# How to count frequency of each categorical variable in a column in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a pyspark dataframe:

```
df.show()
+-----+---+
|  x  |  y|
+-----+---+
|alpha|  1|
|beta |  2|
|gamma|  1|
|alpha|  2|
+-----+---+
```

I want to count how many occurrence `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` there are in column `x`. How do I do this in pyspark?

Comment: Sorry, why not just do `df.groupBy('x').count().show()`?

Comment: May be  the intended ask to group by X and have a Sum of Y .

Answer (score 12):

Use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cube):

```
df.cube("x").count().show()
```